# how to login via machine/vps directly which has blank username and password?

Tags: authentication, .netrc

i am trying to download a file from an website which has login protection but the username and password both it blank and have to login like that.....

so my question is.....

how to download it via curl/wget on my vps ?

is there any .netrc way  or like https://user:pass@site.com    so that my vps can pass it and download it??

site --  https://vaathicloud.cf   -- username -- blank pass --  blank .. just click  .. sign in

pls help......

Answer (score -2):

You have to be owner or moderator for the Team drive.

Buy a Gsuite with your Gmail. Create own team drive and enjoy.

Comment: not team drive its a direct download index